# How to evaluate an arithmetic expression in an "if" statement?

Tags: bash

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
num=1

while [ $num -lt 100 ]
do
if [ $num % 3 -eq "0" ] 

then      
echo "fizz"

elif [ $num % 5 -eq "0" ]
then
echo "buzz"

elif [ $num % 3 -eq "0" ] && [ $num % 5 -eq "0" ]
then          
echo "fizzbuzz" 

else
echo $num

fi

   ((num++))

done
```

It keeps saying `bash: [: too many arguments`.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're asking here, can you please include details about what you're asking?

Comment: @TheLordofTime Now that this has an answer that both clarifies what is being asked and answers the question (and the OP has confirmed this), there's no reason to close this.

Comment: @Eliah: its not possible to undo my close vote, so... yeah... but I do agree with you (no need to ping me about that though...)

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax is:

```
if [ $(($num % 3)) -eq "0" ]
```

From `man bash`:

> **Arithmetic Expansion**
>
> Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression
>   and the  substitution of the result. The format for arithmetic
>   expansion is: `$((expression))`

The expression `$num % 3` must be evaluated before it can be compared using `-eq`.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Eric's answer, you actually can forgo the square brackets if you're simply testing equality with respect to 0. You can also omit the "$" as parameter dereferencing is optional. For the statement in his example,

```
if [ $(($num % 3)) -eq "0" ]
```

is equivalent to

```
if ! ((num % 3))
```

making sure to add in the "!" operator.